# do I need to re-install tidyverse all the time?

Tags: r

I am new to R and just wondering if for every dataset I need to work on, I need to re-install tidyverse? I noticed that on the google Data Analytic program, we are always asked to install. `Package("tidyverse")`

Answer (score 1):

No, you only have to install it once. The program suggests installing it every time to make sure you get it if you don't already have it.

After the first time you install it, it becomes part of your package library, so it is available for scripts to use as long as the package library remains accessible. You can read more about packages and libraries here:

https://hbctraining.github.io/Intro-to-R-flipped/lessons/04_introR_packages.html